# SQL Server Search for Arabic Ya and Kaf when using LIKE Operator

Tags: sql-server, search, sql-like, arabic

[image: Sample Search]

I have problem in searching different types of Arabic Ya. As it is shown in the picture, I get different results.

I have tried the following collations but the result is the same:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.assignmentfiles
ALTER COLUMN submissionTitle NVARCHAR(1000) 
COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS 



ALTER TABLE dbo.assignmentfiles
ALTER COLUMN submissionTitle NVARCHAR(1000) 
COLLATE Frisian_100_CI_AI
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 4):

Use `Arabic_CS_AS_KS_WS` instead of `Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS`

In your case you need something case-sensitive/accent-sensitive since `ي` is not `ى`

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.assignmentfiles
ALTER COLUMN submissionTitle NVARCHAR(1000) 
COLLATE Arabic_CS_AS_KS_WS
```

`_CS_AS_KS_WS` Case-sensitive, accent-sensitive, kana-sensitive, width-sensitive

`_CI_AI_KS_WS` : Case-insensitive, accent-insensitive, kana-sensitive, width-sensitive

[Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16)

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/EKHX5Eeq)

Comment: What I want is something that sees both characters as the same. Is it possible?

Comment: If you want them to be seen as the same then use `Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS` have a look at the demo I shared , Can you share your table definition ?

Comment: The result is still different. This is the table difinition:


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AssignmentFiles](
 [FileId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [FileNameInServer] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 [UploaderUserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [SubmissionTitle] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AssignmentFiles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [FileId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

The collation for table is: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: The column collation are not shown in this description can you run this `sp_help assignmentfiles` and share the result, I need to see the columns collation, see here https://dbfiddle.uk/6JTUeLoQ

Comment: The table collation is: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and the column collation is what we are thinking about. As you see in previous comment, lines are joined and are not readable.

Comment: The table collation is fine, with the column collation ‘Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS’ should fix your problem, please double check the column collation maybe a commit is required !

Comment: I have checked this option, again I check, nothing is changed.